# PHPmailer não funciona o email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Eu tenho o código a seguir:

```
require_once('c:\wamp64\www\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php');


$mail = New PHPMailer();
//$mail-> ErrorInfo;
//exit;
$mail->IsSMTP = true;
//$mail-> ErrorInfo;
//exit;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
//$mail-> ErrorInfo;
//exit;
$mail->Host = "smtp.host.com.br";
//$mail-> ErrorInfo;
//exit;
$mail->Port = 465;
//$mail-> ErrorInfo;
//exit;
$mail->Username = "teste@example.com.br";
$mail->Password = "senha123";
//$mail-> ErrorInfo;
//exit;

$mail->From = "teste@example.com.br";
$mail->FromName = "Suporte";
//$mail-> ErrorInfo;
//exit;
$mail->Subject = "Teste de Envio";
$html = "aa !";
$text = "aa ! ";
$mail->Body = $html;
$mail->AltBody = $text;
//$mail-> ErrorInfo;
//exit;
$mail->AddAddress("teste@example.com.br", "suporte");
//$mail-> ErrorInfo;
//exit;
if (!$mail->Send()){
echo "Erro DNOVO !".$mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "ALELUIA DEU CERTO !";
}
```

Ele retorna o seguinte erro: 
`Erro DNOVO !Could not instantiate mail function.`

Comment: Não seria `$mail->isSMTP()` no lugar de `$mail->isSMTP = true`?

Comment: Eu uso assim:
`require_once '../../lib/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;`

Comment: include(SMTP.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory apareceu isso quando eu tentei trocar pra issmtp();

Comment: eu tentei trocar pra phpmailerautoload.php e continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: @rods, você possui no seu projeto o arquivo `class.smtp.php` que faz parte do `PHPMailer`?

Comment: Sim, consegui com a solução do amigo ali em baixo, mas obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

1. Baixe o repositório do Github deles, usando o botao "Clone or Download" https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
2. Coloca na pasta do projeto
3. Faz o require do autoload
4. E configura com os dados do seu servidor, e usa `$mail->isSMTP()`

   ```
   <?php
   require 'PastaDoPHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; // Troca aqui pela pasta que baixou do repositório.

   $mail = new PHPMailer;

   //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

   $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
   $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
   $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
   $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
   $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

   $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
   $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
   $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
   $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
   $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
   $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

   $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
   $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
   $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

   $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
   $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
   $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

   if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   } else {
       echo 'Message has been sent';
   }
   ```

Com composer é mais fácil. Se precisar de ajuda é só avisar.

Comment: nice, obrigadão!! "aceitei a resposta" ^^